# What are "Software Devices" in Device Manager?

Tags: windows-7, device-manager

I have some items in a group labeled *Software Devices* in Device Manager utility in Windows 7.

[image]

This group contains three items:

- Lightweight Sensors Root Enumerator
- Microsoft Device Association Root Enumerator
- Microsoft IPv4 IPv6 Transition Adapter Bus

The questions are:

- What is "Software Device" group and what do the devices in this group do? Can a device be software at all?
- What are the functions of the three devices I maintained above?

Comment: Related: [How does Windows categorize devices in “Device Manager”?](http://superuser.com/questions/615127/how-does-windows-categorize-devices-in-device-manager?rq=1)

Comment: Regarding "Microsoft Device Association Root Enumerator" I found a good explanation at [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/что-за/1a5b2098-23a6-4e9c-a188-c93bfdd09756). The important part is in english. Since you asked so many questions, I won't post this as an answer :]

Comment: Thank you @nixda but why this driver is not listed in many computers I have ever seen? even not it hidden list.

Comment: Let's try to keep this to one question at a time. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the main question is the function of "Software devices". other question is optionally :D

Answer (score 1):

[Only clue I could find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj124745.aspx)

"Software devices. To test filter drivers, firewalls, and antivirus software that's installed on the test computer."

Sounds like virtual hardware to me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Everything that runs as a driver also appears in Device Manager. This also includes virus scanners and software firewalls and whatnot. Most of these are in the Non-PnP devices category. They are also hidden by default, because they generally are not relevant to end users. You explicitly chose to show hidden devices.

Note: Beginning from Windows 8, [the Non-PnP view no longer exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

An easy-ish to understand example for “software device” is a virtual network adapter. These are used extensively for VPN connections. If you install the OpenVPN client, it installs a virtual network adapter. Rather than connecting to a physical network, it connects to the VPN client, which then encapsulates the traffic appropriately. This is great because applications don’t need to know they’re using a VPN connection. It’s just like any other network connection.

Of course, this is but a single use case. Another common use case is emulating storage drives, either hard disks or optical drives.